# openshift origin M4 - Can't access gears

Tags: nameserver, internal-dns, openshift-origin

I have openshift Origin installed in 3 separate servers

- Broker/Nameserver: openshift.example.com
- Node 1: node-1.example.com
- Node 2: node-2.example.com
- Districts: Small (small gears) node-1.example.com, Large (large gears) node-2.example.com
- DNS configuration: Common domain example.com
- Applications Domain -.example.com

and the entries are registered in the name server of openshift.

When I try to access a gear, ci-dev.example.com, OpenShift redirects me to the Management console. This was not the case when I deployed it on a single node. 
Is there any setting that causes this?